# What is represent by edges when facebook using graph data structure

Tags: facebook-graph-api, data-structures, graph

when learning graph data structure I learned that facebook also use it.And I know nodes represent persons. is edge represent connections between them? when we become a friend with them is there a edge between me and that new friend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes. new connection established and to show connections those social networks use breadth first search(BFS)

Answer (score 0):

People are nodes/vertices. The edges show the connection between them. When person `A` becomes friend with person `B`, an edge is established between two of them. There is no chance of multiple edges between same two vertices.

Refer [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/applications-of-graph-data-structure/) article for more information.

Comment: That was already said, either in the question itself, or in the 4 years old answer. Please, when answering old questions, be sure to bring something new that wasn't said back in the time, and clarify how and why your answer is different, and even better, than the one already given.